# Putting HTML Audio into state REACT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, html5-audio

I have a issue with an audio component I am building. I would like to check if the audio is playing and put it into state as a boolean `isPlaying`. I also would like to have the `currentTime` in state also. Here is what I have so far for the component. When I try bind the audio to state its not working perfectly. So if I go into the dev tools and try and change the state it has no effect on the audio.

```
class AudioPlayer extends  React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this._playingAudio = this._playingAudio.bind(this); 
    this._playPauseUsingState = this._playPauseUsingState.bind(this); 
    this._setAudio = this._setAudio.bind(this); 
    this._syncAudio = this._syncAudio.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      currentTime:0,
      isPlaying:false
    }
  }
  _syncAudio(time) {
    this.setState({
      currentTime:time,
    })
  }

  _setAudio(callback){
    this.setState({
      isPlaying:callback
    })
  }

  _playPauseUsingState(){
    if(this.state.isPlaying) {
      this.audioPlayer.play()
    } else {
      this.audioPlayer.pause()
    }
  }

  _playingAudio(){
    var self = this;
    this.audioPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
      self._syncAudio(this.currentTime)
    })

    this.audioPlayer.addEventListener('playing', function(){
      self._setAudio(true)
    })

    this.audioPlayer.addEventListener('pause', function(){
      self._setAudio(false)
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this._playingAudio();
    this._playPauseUsingState();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    this._playPauseUsingState();
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='audio'>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
        <audio ref={(audio) => {this.audioPlayer = audio}} className="audio-player" src="audio_src.mp3" preload controls></audio>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 ReactDOM.render((
  <AudioPlayer />
),appTarget);
```

Comment: Should isPlaying:callback be different? like callback.target.value or something?

Comment: so if you are referring to the callback in the _setAudio method it works partially. So it changes the state `isPlaying` when the `playing` and `pause` events occur for the audio element. The problem is it is not completely bound to state. If I open the react dev tools  and change the state the audio is unaffected.

Comment: There is issue with reactJs with respect to audio start and stop based on state. we are having same issue in our application in landing page.

Comment: Yeah, I am still have a problems with this. I need to be able to trigger audio events in other components that don't know about this component. I guess the best way to do that would be through state. The actual code for this has state living in the parent. I need to pass a method to a sibling of this component that will be able to use setState for `isPlaying`.